# Unexplained error with json, ajax and jQuery

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({type: 'get',
  mode: 'abort',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'http://localhost/1.php',
  data: {},
  success: function(res){
      alert(res);
  },
  timeout: 10000,
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("ERROR L: " + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
  }

});
```

PHP contains only `{id:1}` and that's it.

When I try to parse the code as is, I get:

```
ERROR L: parsererror (SyntaxError: Unexpected token i)
```

from the error handler I have.

If I change to `dataType:'html',`

Everything works just fine. I am missing something here, probably very very small, what is it?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the property? `{"id":1}`

Comment: @beerbajay is correct. `{id:1}` is _not_ valid [JSON](http://json.org), but `{"id":1}` is.

Comment: @beerbajay put it as an answer, so I can accept it, thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property names in JSON must be quoted:

```
{"id": 1}
```

[The JSON specification](http://json.org/) specifies each name to be of type `string` and defines type string as:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, **wrapped
>   in double quotes**, using backslash escapes. A character is
>   represented as a single character string.

Answer (score 1):

The json isn't valid, change from `{id:1}` to `{"id":1}`

Extra data:

> By far the most common error I’ve encountered relates to object keys. In JSON (unlike in JavaScript) these MUST be double-quoted strings. In fact, ALL strings in JSON must be enclosed in double quotes (JavaScript also allows single quotes; JSON does not).

**Valid:**

```
{ "name": "Simon" }
```

**Invalid:**

```
{ name: "Simon" }
{ 'name': "Simon" }
{ "name": 'Simon' }
```

**[Keep your JSON valid article](http://simonwillison.net/2006/oct/11/json/)**